# VS2008: Make a non-LINQed website LINQed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, linq

I've recently started playing around with ASP.NET and I was just about to connect to a database using LINQ, when I realised that you have to change a bunch of stuff in the project first if you created a normal web site project in Visual Studio 2008.

All the information about LINQed projects in VS2008 that I have found start directly from scratch with a completely new web site. What modifications do I have to make to my project to be able to make use of LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your question can be answered by  [viewing this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117438/getting-started-using-linq-what-do-i-need) on stackoverflow.com.

In short your application will need to have access to System.Linq which comes from the .NET 3.5 framework. If your application is currently using .NET 2.0, it is possible to hack a setup with the CTP packages for Linq prior to it being released with Visual Studio 2008, but you might find it hard when you push your application out to production to a hosting company because you will have to install .dll's into areas you generally don't have access too.

Good luck on your conversion to Linq.